# Execute a command on device over serial connection with Plink

Tags: serial-port, remote-access, putty, plink

This is the first time that I am trying to write a "plink" command that will connect to a device and to have a remote command executed afterwards.  And I am blocked so far.

Here is the command I have tried.

```
plink -v device ( execute shell; whoami)
```

I was expecting the full command process finished right away, but somehow, it hangs. here is the screenshot after I have run the above command,

```
plink -v device ( execute shell; whoami) 
Opening serial device COM1
Configuring baud rate 115200
Configuring 8 data bits
Configuring 1 data bits
Configuring no parity
Configuring XON/XOFF flow control
```

And after i have pushed the extra "Enter" key from my keyboard, then I see the popup of device name, which means the connection part is ready,

```
plink -v device ( execute shell; whoami) 
Opening serial device COM1
Configuring baud rate 115200
Configuring 8 data bits
Configuring 1 data bits
Configuring no parity
Configuring XON/XOFF flow control

FX04DN4N16000408  #
```

What I don't understand is why do I need to run this extra manual step ?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying a command on Plink command-line (or with `-m` switch) works with SSH only, not with serial (or other) connections. The reason is that those connections have no interface for executing a command. They only have input/output.

So, you can use an input redirection with the serial connection, instead. Like this:

```
plink.exe ... < commands.txt
```

or

```
(
  echo your command 1
  echo your command 2
  echo your command 3
) | plink.exe ...
```

---

Related question:
[Authenticating serial connection in Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40877804/850848)

---

You will also probably need to terminate the Plink somehow:
[Send commands via COM port using plink and exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70473206/850848)

Comment: Thank you sir. you've saved my tons of time for that. Running in the "plink.exe ... < input.txt"  way, works for my case.