# Using plink to write a file to a COM port and read back the response from the target

Tags: windows, command-line, serial-port, putty, plink

I want to send a list of commands to a device on my Windows COM port and receive the responses back for further processing.  The target device accepts write commands and query commands.  When I send a write command, nothing is returned.  When I send a query command, a response is returned.  My file (`cmd_list.txt`) will have a long list of commands like this:

```
wr 0x0d 0xff
rr 0x0d
```

The first command writes a value of `0xff` to register `0x0d` and gets no text response.  The second command queries register `0x0d` and returns the value as a string.

I have a PuTTY session named "test" that has the proper baud and other parameters.  From the Windows command line I run this:

```
plink -load test < cmd_list.txt
```

The communication works and I see the correct response to the query appear, but there are two problems.  First, I would like to capture the responses in a text file for further post processing in Octave.  Second, the command window hangs and the command doesn't finish until I enter <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.  The bigger issue is the command window hanging and the command never finishing.

I referenced another article to kill plink and used this command:

```
( taskkill /f /im plink.exe > nul ) | plink -load test < cmd_list.txt
```

When I run this, nothing gets presented to the terminal, but the process does terminate and returns to the command prompt.

I tried redirecting to an output file with this command:

```
( taskkill /f /im plink.exe > nul ) | plink -load test < cmd_list.txt > output.txt
```

But there is nothing in the output.txt file.

I referenced these articles to get my system working to this point:

- [Send commands via COM port using plink and exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473206/send-commands-via-com-port-using-plink-and-exit)
- [Writing script to perform a series of commands over serial connection with PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204011/writing-script-to-perform-a-series-of-commands-over-serial-connection-with-putty/)

Edit: 4/29/22
Per Martin's advice, I tried combining everything to the left of the "|", but I can't get the file that contains my commands to be delivered to plink while also using the taskkill method.  Here's what I tried:

```
(echo cmd_list.txt taskkill /f /im plink.exe > nul ) | plink -load test
```

But I don't get the command prompt to return.  It hangs.

Edit again: 4/29/22
I entered line by line as shown on the example and the terminal responds with "More?" after each entry.  Here is what my terminal process looks like:

```
C:\> (
More? echo cmd_list.txt
More? taskkill /f /im plink.exe > nul
More? ) | plink -load test
| was unexpected at this time

C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

To store the response to a file, just redirect `plink` output:

```
plink ... > output.txt
```

---

For a way to terminate the `plink`, see:
[Send commands via COM port using plink and exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70473206/850848)

Note that you cannot combine `<` and `|` in one commandline, as both produce input to the command. You have to produce all input via `|` (e.g. using the `echo` command), as shown in the linked question.

---

As @Ben Voigt commented, if you want to feed local commands contents to `plink`, you have to use [`type` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type), not `echo`.

And if you need to put everything into a single line, instead of using a batch file, you can do it like:

```
(type cmd_list.txt && taskkill /f /im plink.exe > nul) | plink -load test
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to highlight the answer from a comment above.  This is the command I was looking for:

```
(type cmd_list.txt && taskkill /f /im plink.exe > nul) | plink -load test > output.txt
```

Comment: I've already added this to my answer. Though so far you still never mentioned that you were looking for one-line solution.