# How do I send a serial command repeatedly through PuTTY on a fixed interval

Tags: logging, automation, putty, serial-communication

I am using PuTTY to communicate with a laboratory scale over serial RS232. I plan to use PuTTY's logging functionality to record the readings from the scale over the course of a few hours.

The scale does not have a mode to continuously output its measurement reading, but it does have a command I can send through the Putty terminal to prompt it to do so. I simply need to send 'R'. There are also similar commands to Tare and Zero it.

I would like to automate this so I can set the computer to collect the data every few minutes. From there I have enough python knowledge to clean up the Putty Log automatically for my needs.

So far, I have successfully used the PuTTY Terminal to send command commands to the scale manually and gotten the expected result. I have also figured out how to use a batch file to start PuTTY and the serial connection as desired from other stack overflow questions, but not to send the command on a scheduled basis.

I could dig more into batch scripting, and I have also seen AutoHotKey suggested for a similar issue. Is this functionality built into PuTTY, or is there another pre-made solution? If not, are there any other suggestions for ways I could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Start here:
[Writing script to perform a series of commands over serial connection with PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67204011/850848)

To run the commands repeatedly, you can do something like:

```
:START

plink -serial COMx -sercfg ... < commands.txt

timeout /T 5

goto START
```