# Running command using Plink through Python and serial port?

Tags: python, serial-port, plink

I can open a new `cmd` window and connect with `plink` and serial port through Python.

```
import os
import subprocess

os.system("start cmd /k plink.exe -serial COM4 -sercfg 115200,8,n,1,N")
```

Still good here, but when I want to run `ifconfig`, it didn't work.

```
os.system("ifconfig")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, consider using native Python serial connection implementation, like pySerial, instead of running a console application (`plink`).

See [Full examples of using pySerial package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/676172/850848).

---

Anyway if you run a Windows batch file that does what your Python code, it won't do what you want either:

```
start cmd /k plink.exe -serial COM4 -sercfg 115200,8,n,1,N
ifconfig
```

The `ifconfig` is not a top-level command. It's something that needs to be executed by Plink.

You have to feed the command to the `plink` standard input, see:
[Execute a command on device over serial connection with Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51643735/850848)